# Need a paid SMS sending interface for INTERNATIONAL transactional SMSes

Tags: sms

I am looking for a Paid, Premium service that will allow me to RELIABLY send transactional SMS-es INTERNATIONALLY. Not only to the United States and Canada, but to all over the world. I've been looking around but have had no success finding one. Does anyone know of a platform? I've seen Twilio, but do not think they send International.

I am NOT looking for a bulk spamming service. My need is to send sing up verification codes, password requests, online account notifications and such.

Will appreciate any leads.

Answer (score 1):

I am using twilio for last two years and my experience is amazing.
Check this out
http://www.twilio.com/international-sms

Comment: Thanks. I just signed up for their Beta. Are you speaking from experience when you say your experience is amazing? Or do you work there? If you are using their service to send international SMSes, can you tell me a little more about your pain points? What countries can it NOT send to? I ask because I just tried some others and was not even able to send myself the "Test" messages from their web sites. I'm in India btw.

Comment: I am myself in india, but I am sorry to pass a wrong message. I do not use their service for international SMS I only use it for in USA messaging. My experience with them is as a developer.

Comment: I do work at Twilio, we're always available to answer any questions help@twilio.com